# Consume API hosted on WSO2 Api Manager 3.1.0 using Postman

Tags: api, wso2, jwt

### I am a new user on WSO2 API Manager. I just installed it 2 days back and hosted one simple API on that. It works fine with internal tool. But how to consume it from outside ? eg from Postman or Java code ? Can we make API accessible without any authentication and if i want only jet authentication, how can I do that. please guide. Thanks in advance.

As per suggestion called the API using Curl command and got the token then while calling the
Errors even when providing access token ( which I got after client id and client secret)

Following error when passing Authorization: Bearer 2ee039b0-5cd4-3f31-844c-dd9441593f88​

```
 <ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900908</ams:code>
    <ams:message>Resource forbidden </ams:message>
    <ams:description>Access failure for API: /getcustrates/1.0, version: 1.0 status: (900908) - Resource forbidden </ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

Following error when passing Authorization:Basic 2ee039b0-5cd4-3f31-844c-dd9441593f88​

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900902</ams:code>
    <ams:message>Missing Credentials</ams:message>
    <ams:description>Invalid Credentials. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: 'Authorization : Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'Authorization : Basic ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'apikey: API_KEY'</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to the product, follow the quick start guide[1]. In the end when you invoke the API using the integrated Try-it tool. When you invoke an API using that, it also gives you the equivalent curl command. You can use that to invoke the API externally.

I assume by Jet you meant to say JWT. You can generate JWTs using the client key/secret pair you get from applications you create at the developer portal. You can use this command to generate further tokens.

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Basic EncodeToBase64(<consumer-key>:<consumer-secret>)" -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

or

```
curl -k -u <consumer-key>:<consumer-secret> -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/getting-started/quick-start-guide/

Comment: If I run following curl command in verbose mode for getting access token in WSO2, no output is returned.
curl -k -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json 
https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v1/register

the content of payload.json are:


{
"callbackUrl":"www.google.lk",
"clientName":"rest_api_publisher",
"owner":"admin",
"grantType":"password
 refresh_token",
"saasApp":true
 }

Comment: Following are the log details:

* About to connect() to localhost port 9443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):

Comment: * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US, ST=CA, L=Mountain View, O=WSO2, OU=WSO2, CN=localhost
*        start date: 2019-10-23 07:30:43 GMT
*        expire date: 2022-01-25 07:30:43 GMT
*        subjectAltName: localhost matched
*        issuer: C=US, ST=CA, L=Mountain View, O=WSO2, OU=WSO2, CN=localhost
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> POST /client-registration/v1/register HTTP/1.1

Comment: > User-Agent: curl/7.19.5 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.19.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3
> Host: localhost:9443
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 148
>
< HTTP/1.1 302
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0DEB50A65B9E6EE5AF4B36966D51A320; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: requestedURI=../../client-registration/v1/register; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Location: https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp
< Content-Length: 0

Comment: < Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 06:20:31 GMT
< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):

Comment: Instead of https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v1/register try https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.16/register

Comment: Errors even when providing access token ( which I got after client id and client secret)

Following error when passing Authorization: Bearer 2ee039b0-5cd4-3f31-844c-dd9441593f88

<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900908</ams:code>
    <ams:message>Resource forbidden </ams:message>
    <ams:description>Access failure for API: /getcustrates/1.0, version: 1.0 status: (900908) - Resource forbidden </ams:description>
</ams:fault>

Comment: Following error when passing Authorization:Basic 2ee039b0-5cd4-3f31-844c-dd9441593f88

<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900902</ams:code>
    <ams:message>Missing Credentials</ams:message>
    <ams:description>Invalid Credentials. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: 'Authorization : Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'Authorization : Basic ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'apikey: API_KEY'</ams:description>
</ams:fault>

Comment: Comments are too messy, please update the question.